# Aligning ImageButton in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, imagebutton, android-tablelayout, tablerow

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.yeo.foodapp.MainMenu"
        android:orientation="horizontal">   
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />  
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button4">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchImageButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:src="@drawable/cancelImage"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:contentDescription="" />
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/searchImageButton2"
                    android:layout_width="190dp"
                    android:layout_height="165dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:src="@drawable/cancelImage"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:contentDescription="" />
                <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchImageButton3"
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:src="@drawable/cancelImage"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:contentDescription="" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/searchImageButton4"
                    android:layout_width="126dp"
                    android:layout_height="165dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:src="@drawable/cancelImage"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:contentDescription="" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/searchImageButton5"
                    android:layout_width="126dp"
                    android:layout_height="165dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:src="@drawable/cancelImage"
                    android:layout_column="5"
                    android:contentDescription="" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/searchImageButton6"
                    android:layout_width="126dp"
                    android:layout_height="165dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                    android:src="@drawable/cancelImage"
                    android:layout_column="6"
                    android:contentDescription="" />
            </TableRow>   
        </TableLayout>  
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Cell_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape= "rectangle"  >
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#ff9"/>
</shape>
```

The second table row (searchImageButton4 - 6) does not seem to display at all right after the searchImageButton3. The table seems to be pretty much out the line Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my coding?

Answer (score 2):

Your second `TableRow`'s `layout_column` are starting from 4, which should instead start from 1. Update that and it should work fine.

Below is the updated code for 2nd `TableRow`:

```
       <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchImageButton4"
                android:layout_width="126dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:src="@drawable/cancelImage"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:contentDescription="" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchImageButton5"
                android:layout_width="126dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:src="@drawable/cancelImage"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:contentDescription="" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/searchImageButton6"
                android:layout_width="126dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:src="@drawable/cancelImage"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:contentDescription="" />
       </TableRow>
```

Comment: Please explain what this XML block does and what you've changed.

Comment: i had just changed layout_column for the second row. since first row has column 2 and 3,we cant use column 4,5,6 in 2nd row,because these columns will not be visible in portrait mode.

Comment: @Daryl no, the third column of the tables are still not aligned properly, it appears to be out from the interface